# Does uploading a photo to my web page generate traffic?

Tags: hosting, traffic

I have a website uploaded using the hosting of Plesk and I use the minimum plan (1GB of traffic each month).

Now I want to compress the images of the web so that I don't excede my maximum traffic but I don't know if doing that will generate traffic.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload from the website and not upload directly from your computer to the server you might be using traffic. If you are going to upload file directly to the server you should not incur any traffic. Traffic means how much data users use on your website

Comment: So if I upload it from my computer directly to the server it should be ok, no?

Comment: Yes it should be fine if you upload directly and not through the website